# Why have multiple PNG files been transformed to glitches on the external hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, macbook, adobe-photoshop, png

1. Pictures have been made and edited using Adobe Photoshop and saved as `PNG` on a MacBook
2. If the hard drive of the PC is almost full the edited pictures will be copied to an *external hard drive* in order to safe disk space.
3. A few days later when some of the copied edited pictures are checked on the external harddrive they have been transformed into glitches:

[image]

**Questions**

1. Why have multiple PNG files been transformed to glitches on the external hard drive?
2. Is it possible to solve this?

**System specifications**

- Macbook Pro Retina (Early 2013) Processor: 2.4 GHz
- Intel Core i7 Memory: 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB
- Software: Adobe Photoshop CC 2015

Comment: Not sure what is going on? "Few days later, when I check" means that you didn't check a file right after copying it? That you checked it but few days later is corrupted? It happened with two files (twice) or with hundreds of files?

Comment: I am not sure about the cause of this error, but I can recommend [SuperPNG](http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/). It is a free plugin that provides more control over PNGs than PS's inbuilt one.

Comment: Does it happen with other file formats?

Comment: @cdlvcdlv yeah that's right. I'm running out of free space on my macbook, so i'm copying the png files to the ext hard drive. then i wait until the loading finish and eject the ext hdd without checking them before. it happened two times. Is it possible that the problem comes from photoshop?

Comment: @MichaelD thankyou michael :) btw, is it better than the photoshop's default exporter?

Comment: @Burgi no it doesnt, the other file formats are fine, example: my movies, pdf, word and so on are not affected by the glitch.

Comment: @StefanusWijaya Yeah, for the most part it looks better. You can give it a try if you want.

Comment: If it happened only twice I don't think it's the application, but the copy process. Maybe you removed twice the external hdd before the copy finished. You should verify your png's before moving them and use a tool that verifies the copy. Try [Copy & MD5 Shell Script](http://www.reduser.net/forum/showthread.php?54803-Copy-amp-md5-Shell-Script). It's a script for OSX but it exists a GUI to use it.

Comment: @StefanusWijaya Are you doing a "Eject Device" before unplugging your external hard drive? If you don't do this, you risk data corruption. http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/how-to-eject-usb-in-osx

Comment: @cdlvcdlv i'm really sure that i ejected the hdd after the copy finished. btw, how to use that "Copy & MD5 Shell Script"?

Comment: @misha256 I always eject the ext hdd before i unplug it.

Comment: @Burgi excuse me sir, is there a way to save **png** under specific file size? (ex:under 100kb)

Comment: @StefanusWijaya Yes it is but that is for another question.